# Blend opens with no Language and no version

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend

Ihave installed Blend with VS 2012. While I am opening Blend I cannot select Language and Versions. There data is not available. How can I resolve the issue?
 [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you've installed on Windows 7 I would suggest looking here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/679fb286-2c68-4fa3-9bce-e9fc74d52dea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blend for Visual Studio** as of now only is used for developing [Windows Store Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129478.aspx) and thus needs to be run on Windows 8. There is a preview version of Blend for non Windows Store Applications you can download called the [**Blend + SketchFlow Preview for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702). This will allow you to do Wpf and Silverlight design in Windows 7 and 8. It is a preview release and does not have a go live license. The last thing that I saw as far as timing for the release of final bits is that they will be included with the [Visual Studio Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/).